# Google sheets question - filter sum equation

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of email addresses in one sheet (first column).

I have a list of transactions in another sheet with emails and sale amounts.

I am looking for a formula that adds up all the transaction $ sales for any transactions made by the people (emails) in the first sheet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are too many unknowns to answer this question with any accuracy or efficiency. What are the sheet names? Where is the key data in each sheet (exact ranges)?

Comment: Hi there! Here is an example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18f4WivBkTcTExcoqDkUIyUCU6z4UAaKK2DXTEhKLMUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What I would like to know is: what is the total sales revenue for anyone listed in the "Tag" spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data is very limited (only one row matching one person, in fact). But the following formula should work for you. Place it in a new sheet, in cell A1:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR({"Name","Total"; QUERY(FILTER(Transactions!A2:D,NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Transactions!A2:A,Tags!A:A,1,FALSE)))),"Select Col2, SUM(Col4) GROUP BY Col2 ORDER BY Col2 LABEL SUM(Col4) '' ")},"No Data"))`

This one formula will produce the headers (which you can change within the formula itself as desired) and all results.

`FILTER` filters *in* only 'Transactions' data (names through amounts) where the emails are found in the 'Tags' sheet.

Then `QUERY` returns the name and totals for each match in alphabetical order by name.

If there are no matches, "No Data" will show instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly!
Try this on the sheet, where you only have emails and wanted to get sum of sales amount

> =sumifs(**range_whichHasTransaction** , **range_of_Email_inThat_TransactionsTable** , **Cell_Reference_ofEmail_forWhich_you_want_sum_the_Transaction_Amount**)

it will Look something like this:-

> sumifs(TransactionSheet!B:B,TransactionSheet!A:A,Emails!A2)

Reference

[SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)